# how to redirect after login page in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have Home page. In Home page there are two buttons like imageshow and login. After login successful Its redirect to Page1 and it's working nice.

But now i need to redirect when i click imageShow button. It's open login page and then if login successful it's redirect to page2. So Please give me any Idea.

```
I did                                    successful
 Home Page buttonClick (login)-->LoginPage---------->Page1-->Page2;
I need also                                      successful
    Home Page buttonClick(imageshow)--->LoginPage-------------->Page2;
```

Please give me any idea.
Thanks In Advanced.

Comment: like splash screen after home screen ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I understand your question properly. You have a home page and you want to move to the Login Page and then Page1 and then Page2.

You also have another button called imageshow. And when you click that, it should go to LoginPage and then directly go to Page2 right?

Create a property in your login page like so:

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL goToPage2;
```

If you're using storyboards, in your home view controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"loginSegue"]) {
        Login *loginVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.goToPage2 = YES;
    }
}
```

As shown above, set this `BOOL` to `YES` when you press the imageshow button. And then, inside Login, when you have your success state, check if this `BOOL` is true or not. If true, push to Page2 directly. Else push to Page1.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a property in the Login page & check how the Login page is open when user successfully login the page & display page 1 & 2 accordingly.